# Pass local variable to evaluate() within waitFor() in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to test a website with CasperJS. If the onBlur event is triggered on a certain input field, an attribute somewhere else on the page is updated after some time. I want to wait until this attribute is updated and have concocted the following code to do so:

```
Foo.prototype.setBar = function ( baz ) {
  casper.then( function () {

    // local variable baz can be passed to evaluate
    casper.evaluate( function ( arg1 ) {
      var $inputField = $( 'section.xyz input' );
      $inputField.val( arg1 );
      $inputField.blur();
    }, baz ); // this works just fine

    // local variable baz can not be passed to evaluate within waitFor()
    casper.waitFor( function () {
      return this.evaluate(function ( arg1 ) {
        return __utils__.findOne('mySelector').getAttribute('data-xyz') === arg1;
      }, baz);
    }, function then() {
      casper.log('Attribute with given value was found', 'info');
    }, function timeOut() {
      casper.test.fail('Attribute with given value could not be found');
    }, 10000); // this doesn't work
  });
};
```

Apparently the value of the passed variable `baz` within the waitFor method is null or undefined. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

The signature of waitFor is

```
waitFor(Function testFx[, Function then, Function onTimeout, Number timeout, Object details])
```

As you can see there is no way to pass any arguments to the testFx() function.

The way you can work around it is this: in your previous call to evaluate() create a DOM node (a hidden field for example) and put the value of your baz variable there. Then in the testFx() function just get it from that DOM node.

Comment: `testFx` doesn't actually have any arguments in OP's code. It's the `evaluate` that has the `baz` argument after the callback.

Comment: @ArtjomB. He is passing his `baz` variable instead of the `then()` function because he thinks the syntax for `waitFor()` is similar to `evaluate()` which is wrong. Syntax differs and there is no direct way to pass a variable to a test function called by `waitFor()`

Comment: The indentation was wrong, but to me it looks like `baz` is passed into `this.evaluate`. `testFx` is self-contained aside from the `baz` from a higher scope. What I want to say is that the syntax looks right and this is a proper usage of `casper.waitFor`.